# Проблемы с отображением шрифта

Tags: html, css, шрифты

При подключении шрифта в таком варианте

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url(/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Шрифт не применяется. Однако если переносим в папку выше

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url(/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Шрифт цепляется.

Вопрос в том,почему собственно не применяется?

Эта проблема имеется только в Хроме на платформе Windows,на Mac и *nix такого нет.

Comment: хм, в хроме под виндовс был такой баг в 2014 году, но его пофиксили. Странно.

Comment: Попробуйте поставьте точку в начале пути как указание на текущую директорию `src: url(./fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf);`

Comment: @1000ISLANDS проблема оказалась в шрифте самом который диз предоставил. Скачал с другую версию - весит меньше, но при этом работает везде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в шрифте самом который диз предоставил. Скачал с другую версию - весит меньше, но при этом работает везде.

При возникновении проблемы с отображением шрифта советую попробовать подключить с google, и если все нормально то скачать другой пак.